# VueJS and FontAwesome Import - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vue-cli

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' in '/project/src/plugins'`

Been trying to follow up this tutorial (https://blog.logrocket.com/full-guide-to-using-font-awesome-icons-in-vue-js-apps-5574c74d9b2d/) to upgrade my current fontawesome (4.0.7) to the newest 5.0.12 version on my project, but keep getting this error, that is pretty clear that the project is not finding the lib.

I used

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core 
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons 
npm install --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
```

src/plugins/font-awesome.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faCoffee)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

main.js

```
/* ============
 * Main File
 * ============
 *
 * Will initialize the application.
 */

import Vue from 'vue';

/* ============
 * Plugins
 * ============
 *
 * Import and bootstrap the plugins.
 */

import './plugins/vuex';
import './plugins/axios';
import { i18n } from './plugins/vue-i18n';
import { router } from './plugins/vue-router';
import './plugins/vuex-router-sync';
import './plugins/bootstrap';
import './plugins/font-awesome';
import './plugins/moment';
import './plugins/vuelidate';
import './plugins/scrollto';
import './plugins/filters';
import './plugins/casl';

// Theme css imports
import './assets/css/application.scss';


/* ============
 * Main App
 * ============
 *
 * Last but not least, we import the main application.
 */

import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

store.dispatch('auth/check');

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  /**
   * Bind the Vue instance to the HTML.
   */
  el: '#app',

  /**
   * The localization plugin.
   */
  i18n,

  /**
   * The router.
   */
  router,

  /**
   * The Vuex store.
   */
  store,

  /**
   * Will render the application.
   *
   * @param {Function} h Will create an element.
   */
  render: h => h(App),
});
```

Other plugins are working fine, and the folder actually exists on node_modules.
Any other approach I should try to solve this?

Comment: It's a typo in their documentation. fontawesome not fortawesome. Font not Fort.

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien I wish it was, thats the actual name of the repo (https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome)

Comment: i just checked the tutorial

you should import these packages to your main.js not your font-awesome.js

now since you want to use font-awesome.js i would assume the directory would change as well. Maybe you would need to prefix the paths with ../ or something along that

Comment: thanks @laserany, tried that as well, I got `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' in '/project/src'` that's `main.js` folder, its still not finding it.

Answer (score 7):

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

i had a same problem

webpack css-loader not support **(scss and .css bundling)** you need sass to do

just install sass-loader and node-sass(read below note)

```
npm install -D sass-loader node-sass<----------------see below note before install--------------
```

webpack

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,<-----------------------note placed scss /css---------
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'<--------------------this is you need----------------
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugin omitted
}
```

Note: People make mistake while install `npm install -d sass-loader` however sass-loader brings latest version of sass means you get sass-loader:11.0.0 or above so webpack 4 does not support latest sass-loader.sass loader more than version 11 above for webpack 5.

solutions

your webpack version is 4 so you just need below sass loader version 10

```
npm install -D node-sass
npm install -D sass-loader@^10 <-----------importent step
```

my webpack

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
                use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader','sass-loader'],
              
            },
           
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* import all icons (solid) using fas */
import {fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(fas)
```

Answer (score -5):

npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free

Comment: By looking at the comments, this answer is also wrong.